# Change multi-dimensional array output

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, multidimensional-array, output

I have a variable `$array` which includes an array of data `zip_code`, `distance`, `city`, and `state`.  I want an array of just the `zip_code`'s.  If I do `print_r ($array);` I get the following.

```
Array ( [zip_codes] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [zip_code] => 02822 [distance] => 19.544 [city] => Exeter [state] => RI ) [1] => Array ( [zip_code] => 02871 [distance] => 18.965 [city] => Portsmouth [state] => RI ) [2] => Array ( [zip_code] => 02852 [distance] => 16.092 [city] => North Kingstown [state] => RI )
```

How can I print it, or get it into a format, that it looks like the following:

```
Array ( [0] => 02822 [1] => 02871 [2] => 02852 )
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: `$zipCodes = array_column( $array['zip_codes'], 'zip_code' );` (PHP >= 5.5)

Comment: Fantastic!  This works perfect.  You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

See the php array_column() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php